# How do you assert with delete method void

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm unit testing a Spring boot web app with Mockito. One of my methods is returning a `void`, but if I try to test it, I get compilation errors.

This is the test I wrote:

```java
public void testDeleteActor()throws NetflixException {
    when(actorRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(Mockito.any(Actor.class)));
    assertEquals(null, service.deleteActorById(Mockito.anyLong());
}
```

And this is the method I'm trying to test:

```java
@Override
public void deleteActorById(Long id) throws NetflixException {
    Actor actor = actorRepository
        .findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Actor id not found - " + id));
    actorRepository.delete(actor);
}
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, I'm getting an error with my `assertEquals()` statement:

[image: Screenshot of code with error]

Comment: Help us help you - share some code and the error you're getting

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve? In your piece of code you try to assert that service.deleteActorById() returns null. Even though the method is void apparently thus doesn't return anything. What are you even trying to check, and how is Mockito involved? Also in previous line you setup a mock to return optional with some nonsense - Mockito.any(Actor.class). Perhaps you intended to return Mockito.mock(Actor.class) there? None of your code makes any sense.

Comment: ok i share code in testing and code in service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, your method isn't actually returning `null`, it's returning nothing (`void`). That means that you can't write assertions based on what the method returns. This is the reason why the `assertEquals()` statement is giving you an error.

In stead of testing what the method returns, you can test the expected behaviour of the method. In this example, there are three things we expect:

1. The method should retrieve the actor by its ID.
2. The method should throw an exception if no actor was found with the given ID.
3. The method should delete the actor if it was found.

To implement this these tests, you can use [Mockito's `verify()`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.12.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification) and [AssertJ's `assertThatExceptionOfType()`](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-exception-assertions-assertThatExceptionOfType). For example:

```java
@Test
void deleteActorById_retrievesActorByID() {
    Actor actor = new Actor();
    when(actorRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(actor));
    service.deleteActorById(1L);
    verify(repository).findById(1L);
}

@Test
void deleteActorById_throwsExceptionIfIDNotFound() {
    assertThatExceptionOfType(NotFoundException.class)
        .isThrownBy(() -> service.deleteActorById(1L))
        .withMessage("Actor id not found - 1");
}

@Test
void deleteActorById_deletesActorIfIDFound() {
    Actor actor = new Actor();
    when(actorRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(actor));
    service.deleteActorById(1L);
    verify(actorRepository).delete(actor);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but i see the last two method didnt work in my program and i cant find .hasmessage and must in second function pass an id

Comment: @ayman You're right, I made two typos in the second test. I fixed the missing parameter (should be `1L` or anything you'd like, as long as you change the message). The `hasMessage()` method should actually be `withMessage()` (as you can see in the documentation I linked in my answer). I fixed both issues.

Comment: when i want test the second function for example "deleteActorById_throwsExceptionIfIDNotFound" return error and the test doesnt succeeded java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=deleteActorById_throwsExceptionIfIDNotFound], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=deleteActorById_throwsExceptionIfIDNotFound(actortest.ActorServiceTesting)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=actortest.ActorServiceTesting,fLeadingIdentifier=deleteActorById_throwsExceptionIfIDNotFound]]